# How Do I Change The Gradle Output Directories?

Tags: gradle

Maven puts its output in "target". Gradle puts its output in "build".

How can I make gradle put its output in "target" too?

The output of the war plugin is "build/libs/project.war"; how can I make it "target/project.war"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at the [javadocs](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Project.html) or the [userguide](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/writing_build_scripts.html). There's a method `setBuildDir`. You need to pass a path where you want artifacts to be placed.
e.g.

```
// Use maven output dir
setBuildDir 'target'
```

[Wicket](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/wicket/trunk/build.gradle) is an example of a project that does this.